# MySQL select * from table1,table2 as 'test'

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in MySQL.

```
SELECT table1.column1, test.column2 
FROM table1,table2 AS test 
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.column3 = table1.column1 
WHERE test.column2 = table1.column1
```

**I get this error:**

> Unknown column 'table1.column1' in 'on clause'

Comment: Sure that column1 exists? If so use an 'as' for this one too, might help

Comment: try `SELECT table1.column1,test.column2 FROM table1,table2 test, table3 WHERE table3.column3=table1.column1 AND test.column2=table1.column1`. 2 possibilities, joining every tables between them using `INNER JOIN` or the old method which is joining them in the `WHERE` clause after listing the tables in the `FROM`. I am not sure you can mix the methods

Comment: Please provide detail of your database structure (use sqlfiddle ideally). Otherwise its not possible to provide a definitive answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use few tables in FROM you must use ():

`from (table1,table2)`

Comment: This is not true, and not relevant either.

The person asking the question hasn't provided us with any details of the database structure, so we don't know whether table1.column1 actually exists.

Comment: It is working like this : from (table1,table2 as test)

Comment: @SimonWoolf it is true and question is clear enough

Comment: @hayal.et yes, I focused on solution and forgot about your alias

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 methods for joining tables :

using INNER JOIN on EVERY tables using their key :

```
SELECT table1.column1,test.column2 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 test  
    ON table1.column1=test.column2
INNER JOIN table3 
    ON test.column2=table3.column3
```

The second one is the old one which is to list every tables in the FROM clause, then linking them in the WHERE clause like :

```
SELECT table1.column1,test.column2 
FROM table1,table2 test, table3 
WHERE table3.column3=table1.column1 AND test.column2=table1.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query can simply modify like the below:

```
Select t1.column1, test.column2 
from table1 as t1
join table2 as test on test.column2 = t1.column1
join table3 as t3 on t3.column3 = t1.column1
```

Here t1, test, t3  are table alias

Comment: Until the user provides details of their database structure, there is no way of knowing whether this will work.